# How to declare string to be equal on textbox.text after that

Tags: c#

where is the mistake here:

```
    static int count = 0;
    string s;
    private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtSend.Text = s;
        count++;

        label5.Text = count.ToString("X2");

        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

        s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +
        (label5.Text.ToString());

    }
```

on first click i get a click value 01, but dont get the txtsend.text ... on second click i get value 02 but in txtsend.text i get the 4D-1A-2B-3C-01

Comment: What would you like to have in `txtsend.text` after the second click? BTW is this Web application ow WPF/WinForms?

Comment: i need to have 4D-1A-2B-02 - (02 is number of clicks)
on the first click i need 4D-1D-2B-01 - (01 is number of clicks)

Comment: Is this WEB or Desctop appliction?what about 3C before 02?

Comment: 3C is a constant ... just a number and letter ...

Answer (score 3):

Every time you change string variable, it is recreated.

On the first click, `textbox` and `s` are pointing to `null`, after that varible `s` is changed and it is pointing to `new value`, but `textbox` still points to `null`;

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
static int count = 0;
string s;
private void SetClock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    count++;
    label5.Text = count.ToString("X2");
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    s = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +(label5.Text);
    txtSend.Text = s; 

    //Set your s before assign to txtSend.Text

    //or you can do without s like
    //txtSend.Text = "4D-" + "1A-" + "2B-" + "3C-" +(label5.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Yograj :) i cant undetstand why the txtSend value must be under all those code ...

Comment: See answer of JesseJames